# Determining the amount of letters in each word of a string in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, cin

I'm new to c++ and coding in general and I ran into a bit of an issue in one of my assignments. I'm just looking for some input and hopefully an explanation on why my code isn't working.

I'm trying to get input from a user and use a `cin.get()` function to count all the characters in that string. I do this because I want to determine the letters in each word of the string. Now my issues are I can't get it to print the result correctly.

My question is: **Why can't I get a result when I try to determine if my variable `chr`** is a '\n' character? `chr` is the variable that hold the value of the current character being read by the `cin.get()` function) is a `'\n'`.
I want to be able to update the parameters (word1, word2.....) of my function `countWordsByLegth()` when the current value of `chr` is `'\n'` or in other words the end of the string.

The following code, for example, won't run and it's the only way I know how to update my parameter for a string that contains no spaces (one word strings):

```
if (counter == 5 && chr == '\n')
{
    ++word5;
    counter =0;
}
```

Here's my code for reference. The function `isWhitespace()` just determines if the character is one of the following `'\n'` , `'\r'` , `'\t'`):

```
while (cin.get(chr) && chr != '\n')
{
    counter++;
    if (isWhitespace(chr))
        {   
            --counter;
            //test = true;
        }
                if (counter == 5 && chr == '\n')
                {
                    ++word5;
                    counter =0;
                }
                if (counter == 4 && chr =='\n')
                {
                    ++word4;
                    counter =0;
                }
                if (counter == 3 && chr =='\n')
                {
                    ++word3;
                    counter =0;
                }
                if (counter == 2 && chr == '\n')
                {
                    ++word2;
                    counter =0;
                }
                if (counter ==1 && chr == '\n')
                {
                    ++word1;
                    counter =0;
                }
        cout << counter << endl; // Test code {delete later}
}
cout << "This is the total of word5: " << word5 << endl;
```

}

Comment: Please add to the question the test string, what result is produced and what result did You expect.

Comment: your `while` tests if `chr != '\n'`. Therefor you will never hit any of the `if` statements as they are looking for the `\n`

Comment: It seems like you could use a loop instead of all those if's.

Comment: @churill: You probably mean array or map.

Comment: How about: `std::string s; std::cin >> s; std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;`?

Comment: @Jarod42 No, I mean a loop. Most likely in combination with a `vector`. But still a loop to shorten almost identical code.

Comment: @churill: I meant: `if (1 <= count && count <= 5) { ++words[counter]; count = 0;}`, No loops.

Comment: @Jarod42 I still meant a loop, but your solution actually looks better ^^

Comment: My suspicion was that the (cin.get(chr) && chr != '\n') prevented anything in the loop from reading a ' \n '. But the problem is if I take it out and just write (cin.get(chr)), it never stops asking the user for input. Any ideas on how to solve this?. As far using using vectors and arrays, it's just something I've never used before and according to my instructions for the assignment I cant use them.

Comment: I guess you could put the `if`s outside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::string.length()` to get the amount of chars in a string.
The `length()` function returns the number of chars in the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  s = "test";
  std::cout << "The string has " << s.length() << " letters!";
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ here you can read about the different functions that you can use with strings.

Comment: Hi, I think that instead of pointing out to the C++ doc, you should include the actual ` function that returns the size of the string` to your answer. This way, you would answer precisely the question

Comment: That only works correctly for single-byte encodings. `std::string` can well contain a utf-8 encoded string, as it normally does on Linux.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: unicode's length is "ambiguous" anyway see [utf8everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/#myth.strlen)

Comment: @Jarod42 How many bytes a string or word occupies is a totally different question from how many individual characters a string is comprised of. This answers the former question.